# TypeScript Angular PUT Request method not supported

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am currently working on an Angular Project with Spring Boot. I am new to Web programming, so I have some hurdles to overcome yet. What I would like to do is, send a PUT Request to the Backend to change the name of an existing object (in this example it's the name of a category). But I always get a 415 Error when I want to send the Request. I'm not sure how and where to set the MediaType correctly. Could someone help me out?

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from "../../types/category";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { CategoryService } from "../../services/category.service";
import { CategoryCustomValidatorService } from "../../validators/category-custom-validator.service";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-edit-category',
    templateUrl: './edit-category.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./edit-category.component.scss']
})
export class EditCategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    public createForm?: FormGroup;
    public category: Category = {id: '', name: '', description: ''};

    public onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    public headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application-json'});

    @Output()
    public categoryCreateEvent: EventEmitter<Category> = new EventEmitter<Category>();

    public constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private categoryService: CategoryService,
        private customValidatorService: CategoryCustomValidatorService
    ) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initCreateForm();
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.onDestroy$.next();
    }

    public onSubmit(): void {
        if (this.createForm && this.createForm.valid) {

            const {name, description} = this.createForm.getRawValue();

            this.category.name = name;
            this.category.description = description;
            this.categoryService.findById(this.category.id);
            this.categoryService
                .update(this.category)
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
                )
                .subscribe((category: Category) => {
                    this.onCreateSuccess(category);
                });
        }
    }
```

I already tried to set the media type to application/JSON in the component class, but it didn't work for me. Also when I send the request via Postman, everything works.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Category } from "../types/category";
import { HttpClientService } from "../../HttpParameters/services/http-client.service";

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

    private categoryUrl: string = "categories";

    public constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) {
    }

    public findAll(): Observable<Category[]> {
        return this.httpClientService.get<Category[]>(this.categoryUrl);
    }

    public findById(id: string): Observable<Category> {
        return this.httpClientService.get<Category>(this.categoryUrl);
    }

    public create(category: Category): Observable<Category> {
        return this.httpClientService.post<Category>(this.categoryUrl, category);
    }

    public isNameUnique(name: string): Observable<boolean> {
        const params = {
            name: name.trim()
        };
        return this.httpClientService.get<boolean>(`${this.categoryUrl}/validation`, {params});
    }

    public update(category: Category): Observable<Category> {
        return this.httpClientService.put<Category>(`${this.categoryUrl}`, category);
    }
}
```

this is my CategoryService so far.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpParameters } from "src/app/HttpParameters/types/HttpParameters";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {
    protected apiUrl = environment.apiPath;

    public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public get<T>(path: string, param?: HttpParameters): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${this.apiUrl}/${path}`, param);
    }

    public post<T>(path: string, object: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${this.apiUrl}/${path}`, object);
    }

    public put<T>(path: string, param?: HttpParameters): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.put<T>(`${this.apiUrl}/${path}`, path);
    }

    public delete<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.delete<T>(`${this.apiUrl}/${path}`);
    }
}
```

and here is the HttpClientService.

Also this is my Backend (Spring Boot) code.

```
package de.features.category.controller;

import de.detim.loginvault.features.category.model.Category;
import de.detim.loginvault.features.category.service.CategoryService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("categories")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryController {

    private final CategoryService categoryService;

    @PostMapping
    public Category create(@RequestBody Category category) {
        return categoryService.create(category);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        categoryService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Set<Category> findAll() {
        return categoryService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Category findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return categoryService.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/validation")
    public boolean isNameValid(@RequestParam String name) {
        return categoryService.isNameValid(name);
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public void update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Category category) {
        categoryService.updateById(id, category);
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, WebConfigCategories {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE");
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappingsCategories(CorsRegistry registryCat) {
        registryCat.addMapping("/categories/{id}")
                   .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                   .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE");
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your CategoryService.ts file, thanks.

Comment: hi, sorry for my late reply. I added the CategoryService.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a path as a request body in the put method of the HttpClientService.
You should probably pass the updated object, similarly to the post method that you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I changed it so that I now am passing the object. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you post the updated code, also it would be helpful to see the backend code for this resource.

Comment: yup, its updated now.